# How parse soap Fault.detail(lxml.etree._Element) from zeep python library

Tags: python, soap, zeep

I'm trying get error detail, when I'm calling soap service with zeep.

How parse zeep.exceptions.Fault.detail? It's return lxml.etree._Element.

I'm using this code:

```
try:
    client = Client(wsdl=self.__wsdl)
    response = client.service.CustomerInformation(CustomerInformationService=self.service, faultStyle='wsdl')
except Fault as error:
    detail = error.detail
    # parse detail here
```

Here is response XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Body >
        <soap-env:Fault  >
            <faultcode>soap-env:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Client Error</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <ouaf:Fault xmlns:ouaf="urn:oracle:ouaf">
                    <ResponseStatus>F</ResponseStatus>
                    <ResponseCode>2013</ResponseCode>
                    <ResponseText>
                            Error while executing the request:
                            (Server Message)
                                Category: 90006
                                Number: 32200
                                Call Sequence: 
                                Program Name: CustomerInformationService
                                Text: The personal account was not found: 9134211141
                                Description:  
                                Table: null
                                Field: null
                    </ResponseText>
                    <ResponseData numParm="1"  text="The personal account was not found: 9134211141"  category="90006"  number="32200"  parm1="9134211141"  />
                </ouaf:Fault>
            </detail>
        </soap-env:Fault>
    </soap-env:Body >
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Diffinition of 'Fault' type from xml data exist in my wsdl.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but looking for the answer got me here and now I also know how to do it.

The URL to wsdl in the example is made up as well as the credentials.

```py
import zeep

url_to_wsdl = 'www.some_SOAP_site.com/soap?wsdl'

client = zeep.Client(url_to_wsdl)

credentials = {
    'login' : 'my_login',
    'pass' : 'my_pass'
}

my_query = "SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1"

try:
    client.service.query(my_query)
except zeep.exceptions.Fault as fault:
    parsed_fault_detail = client.wsdl.types.deserialize(fault.detail[0])

print(parsed_fault_detail)
```

Results in

```
{
    'errorCode': 'INVALID_SESSION',
    'errorMessage': 'Invalid session!'
}
```

Don't forget the `[0]` after `fault.detail` and try incrementing it to see if there are more error details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `error.code` or `error.message` to match with the error that you want to look for.

https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/blob/master/src/zeep/exceptions.py#L53

If you can't see anything in `error.detail`, consider sending a PR to the python-zeep project.

Comment: I see this information, but I need parse detail with my WSLD:
[ticket #392](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/392)